# How to run a closure in a completion closure while fetching data from an api?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a function with a completion handler. The Function calls an API to get latitudes and longitudes. These latitudes and longitudes are passed to completion handler for calculating miles. `

```
    @objc func getActiveData(completion:@escaping (String,String) -> Int32) {

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://*********************")
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)
    let session = URLSession.init(configuration: .default, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: .main)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data,resposne,error in
        if let rdata = data {
            do{
            if let responseDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: rdata, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

                let statusCode = responseDictionary["status_code"] as! Int

                if statusCode == 1 {
                if let data: NSDictionary = responseDictionary.object(forKey: "data") as? NSDictionary{


                    let data1: NSArray = data["data"] as! NSArray
                    let data4 = (data1).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
                    var milesList: [Int32] = []
                    let x = data1.count
                    print("x = ",x)
                    for i in 0..<x {
                        let order: NSDictionary = data1[i] as! NSDictionary
                        let storeLat: String = order["pickup_latitude"] as! String
                        let storeLong: String = order["pickup_longitude"] as! String
                        let miles = completion(storeLat, storeLong)
                        milesList.append(miles)
                        print("from for loop",milesList)
                    }
                    print(milesList)

                    //print(data4)
                    self.data = data1
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }



                }
                else {
                    self.data = []
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }

    })
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.activeRefresher.endRefreshing()
    //self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

    task.resume()
}`
```

I am calling the completion handler inside for loop to get miles.
`

```
     getActiveData(){ (lat,long) -> Int32 in
        var value:Int32 = 0
        print(lat,long)
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=\(Latitude!),\(Longitude!)&destinations=\(lat),\(long)&mode=driving&key=******************************")
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)
        let session = URLSession.init(configuration: .default, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: .main)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data,resposne,error in
            if let rdata = data {
                do{
                 if let responseDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: rdata, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

                    let statusCode = responseDictionary["status"] as! String

                    if statusCode == "OK" {
                        if let data: NSArray = responseDictionary.object(forKey: "rows") as? NSArray{
                            //print(data)
                            let data1: NSDictionary = data[0] as! NSDictionary
                            let elements: NSArray = data1["elements"] as! NSArray
                            let object: NSDictionary = elements[0] as! NSDictionary
                            //print(object["distance"] ?? [:])
                            if object["status"] as! String == "OK" {
                                let distance: NSDictionary = object["distance"] as! NSDictionary
                                value = distance["value"] as! Int32
                                print("miles from func = ",value)
                            }


                        }



                    }

                }
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }

        })
        task.resume()
        print(value)
        return value


    }`
```

But XCode is executing the task closure after the completion of for loop. Here is the screenshot of the debug area.

[image]

I want to execute it in the for loop.

Comment: This cannot work. You need `DispatchGroup` and you have to put the code in the completion handler into an extra method with its own completion handler. By the way this is Swift: Don't use `NSURL`, `NSURLRequest` `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSMutable...`. Use native types

Comment: Could you please post some code. I am stuck with this.

Comment: Sorry, it's more than *some code*

Comment: Maybe, but I have started swift just 15 days ago

Comment: maybe try again, breaking down the logic into smaller functions to get a better understanding of what is happening, when and in which order.

Comment: I am trying it for 2 days. Could you please elaborate what @vadian has commented

Comment: That works superbly. Thanks !!! @Vadian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two methods and `DispatchGroup`

```
@objc func getActiveData()
```

without the completion handler and

```
func getMiles(lat: String, long: String, completion: @escaping (Int32) -> Void)
```

Put the code inside the closure of your `getActiveData` in `getMiles`, then replace

```
value = distance["value"] as! Int32
print("miles from func = ",value)
```

with

```
value = distance["value"] as! Int32
completion(value)
```

and delete

```
return value
```

---

The workflow is (only the relevant lines)

```
func getActiveData() {

...
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data,resposne,error in

        ...
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        ...

        for i in 0..<x {
           let order = data1[i] as! [String:Any]
           let storeLat = order["pickup_latitude"] as! String
           let storeLong = order["pickup_longitude"] as! String
           group.enter()
           self.getMiles(lat: storeLat, long: storeLong) { miles in
               self.milesList.append(miles)
               group.leave()
           }
        }
        group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
            self.data = data1
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. The list is now populated but in the wrong order. I tried to use DispatchQueue.main.sync { self.getmiles.append(miles) } but it didn't work. Any idea how to tackle this problem

Comment: Save also the index `i` in `milesList` and sort the list before reloading the table view

Comment: Yes, that works. Instead of appending, I just did -> milesList [i] = miles